# Accessing files outside the document root with Apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, document-root

I have a project setup and i'm trying to access a file from a temp folder on the server.

The document root for the website is similar to this:

/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/mywebsite.com (of the letters have proper names).

The file I need to read lives here:

/a/b/c/myfile.txt

I've tried symbolic links but may have done them wrong... any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to access the file? Using what?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create a directory alias:

```
<VirtualHost....>

..... stuff .....

Alias /mydir /a/b/c

</VirtualHost>
```

then you could access the text file like so:

```
domain.com/mydir/myfile.txt
```

Note that this needs to take place in the central configuration file, not a `.htaccess` file.

Symlinks are an option too. Make sure you have

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

turned on.

Comment: Can anyone be more specific about this? I have a folder in another drive which I want to access. Where do I paste that block of code?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. Even after updating my main config file and restarting, Apache still returns "No Such Resource" page.