# php access files outside of apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a project where Red5 is recording videos. I need PHP to be able to access the videos and move them so they can be accessed by HTML.

How can I do this?

I found this post: [Accessing files outside the document root with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache)

But it involves updating some file that was never specified. And I'm not sure it is a viable solution in this case anyway.

lee

Answer (score 3):

PHP by default can already access files outside the web root, unless restricted with an `open_basedir` directive (or safe mode, but hope you're not in that cage).

It's normally a good practice to insert within a VirtualHost configuration an `open_basedir` restriction. You can specify multiple directories separated by `:` on Linux and `;` on windows.

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/s/stage:/usr/share/php:/your/dir
```

To access those files either use an absolute path or a path relative to the position of the PHP file called. (So you'll have to `../` to reach levels above).

Also be sure that directories in which you want to write to are assigned to the webserver user and have write permission.

Comment: Would it be possible to send the command 'cp /a/b/file /g/h/file' ?

Comment: use PHP [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) though, although I am not sure if it's a good idea to copy media files on the fly... What are you trying to achieve? Copy when they pay?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - You are overcomplicating things in your mind. 1) The `cp` command was already two decades old when the web was invented. 2) PHP can copy files natively.

Comment: stivlo - Red5 records video through Flash. However, it records to its own directory. I want to be able to move that FLV to a place that it can be accessed by a webpage.

Comment: On Linux you can consider making a symbolic link and activate the follow symbolic link option in Apache.