# Apache httpd Virtual host (it succeeds on /var/www but fails on /www)

Tags: apache, centos7

I installed `Apache httpd` on `CentOS 7` by `yum`. `httpd` is installed under `/etc/httpd` with tree

```
/etc/httpd
 |-- conf/
 |-- conf.d/
 |-- conf.module.d/
 |-- ...
```

Everything is default, now I want to try virtual host by adding a config file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/test
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and an `html` file `/www/text/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> test </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But `www.example.com` in my browser still direct to the default page.

Then I tried a different directory other than `/www/test` after reading some articles (I also added an html file `/var/www/test/index.html`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This time it works! `www.example.com` in my browser does show the right page.

So obviously the problem is the directory `/www`, but why does `httpd` fail on `/www` while succeeding on `/var/www`? What's the difference? By the way, I have granted permission on `/www` to user `apache`

Comment: Do you have have  "/www" directory?

Comment: Go in your host directory where you have your application ("test"), do pwd, get absolute path, try to replace that in DocumentRoot, also check apache service status and logs

Comment: Yes, I have directory /www. I tried changing DocumentRoot to /www/test (and delete virtual host config file), it directs to the default page. Something must be wrong, I guess?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache

Comment: You should use apache port forwarding feature to redirect your request to desired url in virtualhost (No need to remove virtualhost).